# Specified cast is not valid error using C# in Visual studio

Tags: c#

I am attempting to extract the price of a product from my Access database based on the product ID. However, I have encountered the System.InvalidCastException error when attempting to execute this action.

Here's the paragraph from my code which the error originated from:

```
protected void btnBuy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    string strProductId, strSQLSelect, strSQL;
    decimal decUnitPrice;

    strSQLSelect = "SELECT PromotionPrice FROM Products WHERE ProductId = @ProductID";
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQLSelect, mDB
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductId", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = strProductId;
    object oUnitPrice = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    decUnitPrice = (decimal)oUnitPrice; //<-- Error code
```

And here are the Stack Trace exception codes:

```
[InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
   details.btnBuy_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\wesnpets\details.aspx.cs:60
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9690930
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3562
```

Visual Studio indicated that the last line was the one which caused the error. I have checked all over my codes as well as my database that the format for the relevant field was properly set to Decimal. However, I am still unable to find a solution for this issue.

So is there anything that I might have missed out? Hopefully, you can suggest some possible solutions for this. Thanks!

Comment: Is the field nullable in the DB?

Comment: Could you show the exception message?

Answer (score 0):

The C# type decimal represents a 128 bit number, whereas decimal in the database is a bit different and can represent various things.  You can probably get the database decimal as a string and use Decimal.Parse() to get decUnitPRice.

Answer (score 0):

I think three things might happen:

- PromotionalPrice column is not decimal
- The query returns no rows.
- The PromotionalPrice column is null on the row

I would do the following to deal with that:

```
if (oUnitPrice == null || Convert.IsDbNull(oUnitPrice)) 
{
   // no nows or PromotionalPrice column is null
}
else
{
   // if oUnitPrice is not decimal 
   // but it can be converted to decimal it will work
   decUnitPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(oUnitPrice);
}
```

Disclaimer: I wrote the above code directly on the answer, so It might not compile.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the return value of that expression is just a different (maybe numeric) type but since it's boxed as an `object` you cannot use casts for numeric conversions (note that casting `int` to `decimal` is a totally different operation than casting `object` to `decimal`). Example:

object d = 1.2;
  var x = (decimal)d;

will fail, however `(decimal)(double)d` will succeed.

I'd suggest you use `Convert.ToDecimal` instead of casting, which will do the right thing based on the actual type of the operand here.